# How to use the same column as check and condition in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, database, where-clause

Is it possible to filter the column based on this exactly column in condition? I need to count the number of distinct ids in every range of lifetimes. For example, if lifetime = 10, I need to count all the unique ids in range where lifetime is between 10 and 30.

If I write

```
SELECT 
  lifetime, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT id_ru) AS number
FROM lifetime_count
WHERE lifetime BETWEEN lifetime AND 30
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
LIMIT 15
```

I get different results if I hardcode the needed lifetime value like this, for example

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT id_ru) AS number
FROM lifetime_count
WHERE lifetime BETWEEN 0 AND 30

SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT id_ru) AS number
FROM lifetime_count
WHERE lifetime BETWEEN 1 AND 30

...
```

Comment: Can you share some sample input data and corresponding expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can also approach this problem by:

- counting for each lifetime the distinct values of id_ru, using the `COUNT` aggregation function
- computing a running sum over this count, using the window function `SUM`

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT lifetime, 
           COUNT(DISTINCT id_ru) AS cnt
    FROM tab
    GROUP BY lifetime
    ORDER BY lifetime
)
SELECT lifetime, 
       SUM(cnt) OVER(ORDER BY lifetime DESC) AS cnt 
FROM cte
ORDER BY lifetime
```

Here's a MySQL [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vqV5u4dLJhHy5CGVWbJdQF/2) that can give you the general idea and something to play with, though these constructs can be found in any DBMS.

Comment: it counts the whole sum of ids based on lifetime and therefore one id can be counted several times in one range and this is not correct for my task, as I need the number of unique users in every range from lifetime to 30.

Comment: Check the updated answer or update your post with some sample input data and expected output for more clarity. Note that the ids associated to the value 20 can be found in the ranges of values [1,30], [2,30], [3,30] etc..., hence ids counted several times is expectable.